# Is Google account neccessary for Google Play Game Services?

Tags: android, ios, google-play-services, multiplayer

I want to use Google Play Game Services to implement multiplayer in my game. The game will be deployed on Android and iOS.

Is it neccesary for iOS user to have an Google account in order to use GPGS ?

Comment: If this question is solved, please mark it as solved.

Comment: @Abkarino I will, but I'm still waiting for some authoritative answer.

Comment: I hope you get one. I want to create a multiplayer game as well but I want to integrate Facebook, yet I can't find a good api to use but Google which limits to G+ circles and yet I don't have a developer account.

Comment: @Abkarino Same story here :) If you find some good api, feel free to post about this.

Comment: Realtime or turn-base ? how many users do you expect ? would you accept services that has ads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the users using your game, They must sign in with a Google account to use multiplayer so that Google could generate an ID of the user to store in the db for achievement or for game search.

And if they do like to play with a friend, the friend must be in their circles.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I believe that the user needs to have a Google account. When you go to the Developer Console to register the game (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/), you get prompted for signin via Google.